# How to make an Instagram-like error label

Tags: ios, objective-c

So, I have been banging my head against a wall trying to figure out a way to accomplish this.  My goal is to have an error label that appears when a username/password is entered incorrectly, but I want something different than just unhiding a label with red text (which is what I currently have).  If you use Instagram, I am trying to get a label to show up like when you enter your password correctly and the label gets pushed (slid) down from under the navigation bar.

So far I have tried creating a label programatically and moving it, but the label always starts under the navigation bar so it doesn't seem to "slide" like in Instagram.  I have also tried to create a new VC with a clear background and just the label and present it with a segue but that didn't work either.

If anyone can let me know how this is done, I would be very grateful.

Thanks,

Brandon

Comment: Post some code of what you have tried

Comment: not sure what it looks like on Instagram, but sounds like you want a [custom animation](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes)

Comment: I think the custom animation might work, but the problem I was running into with something like that is I can not get the label to start "behind" the navigation bar, every time I create it the 0,0 is right under the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out YRDropdownView. It is a library, with which you can easily create notifications very similar to those used by Instagram.

http://buildinternet.com/2012/02/yrdropdownview-a-polite-uialertview-alternative-for-ios/

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was hoping for, thank you so much!

Comment: Nice answer. I think I'll use this in my app! @BrandonShega, check this off if it works!